# Condition on ratio related to bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I know that for a bipartite graph, the adjacency matrix can be written as
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0_{rr} & B \\ B^T  & 0_{ss}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Let $M_{-}$ be the signed incidence matrix and let $C$ be the matrix defined as
\begin{align}
C = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0_{rr} & B \\ 0_{rs}  & 0_{ss}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
I'm interested to find, under which conditions on the graph, the ratio
\begin{align}
\kappa = \frac{\sigma_{\max}(C)}{\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(M_{-})}
\end{align}
is very small, (i.e. almost zero)? where $\sigma_{\max}(C)$ is the maximum singular value of the matrix $C$ and $\tilde{\sigma}_{\min}(M_{-})$ is is the minimum non-zero singular value of $M_{-}$.